# Jquery not working in my wordpress page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am very new to Wordpress and Jquery.. Here is my problem.
Need to create a simple power calculator in my wp page  by selecting house hold items with checkerbox. Selected checker box values are sum up and should be shown on the fly!
here is my whole code changed as suggested ($=jQuery.noConflict();) Still not working :(

```
         <head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$=jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function () {

function sumRows() {
    var sum = 0,
        total = $('#total');
    $('tr').each(function () {
        var amount = $(this).find('input[name="amount"]'),
            checkbox = $(this).find('input[name="include"]');
        if (checkbox.is(':checked') && amount.val().length > 0) {
            sum += parseInt(amount.val(), 10);
        }
    });
    total.text(sum);
 }

 // calculate sum anytime checkbox is checked or amount is changed
 $('input[name="amount"], input[name="include"]').on('change keyup blur', sumRows);

 });

      </script>



  </head>

 <body>

        <div id="total" style="color:red">0</div>
          <table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="0" size="6" name="amount"></td>
    <td>
        <input name="include" type="checkbox">
    </td>
   </tr>

    <tr>
     <td><input type="text" value="0" size="6" name="amount"></td>
        <td>
                  <input name="include" type="checkbox">
                </td>
         </tr>
            <tr>
           <td><input type="text" value="0" size="6" name="amount"></td>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="include">
    </td>
                     </tr>
    </table>
     </html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error? have u tried [jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)?

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
I have already did it before but thumps down :/ ..

Comment: in your scenario you need to use $j instead of $

Comment: Tried just now but no output!.The strange thing I've noticed that in wordpress code editor,I put some simple jquery functions like click events and its WORKING fine with $ ,and if i put a new line space between code, NOT WORKING!! why?

Comment: i tried it with a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbseqmf6/1/ can u try it that way again?

Comment: I tried every way you suggested! the code working fine in everywhere except my wordpress page. anyways I am gonna seek other ways to accomplish my scenario. Thanks for the time you spent for me..

Answer (score 1):

You can't use jQuery handy function `$()` in Wordpress plugin. You have to use `jQuery()` or `jQuery.noConflict()` to avoid conflicts between jQuery and Wordpress.

So:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {

   function sumRows() {
    var sum = 0,
        total = jQuery('#total');
    jQuery('tr').each(function () {
        var amount = jQuery(this).find('input[name="amount"]'),
            checkbox = jQuery(this).find('input[name="include"]');
        if (checkbox.is(':checked') && amount.val().length > 0) {
            sum += parseInt(amount.val(), 10);
        }
    });
    total.text(sum);
}

   // calculate sum anytime checkbox is checked or amount is changed
   jQuery('input[name="amount"], input[name="include"]').on('change keyup blur',   sumRows);

});
```

Or using [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/):

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via $j(...)
$j(document).ready(function(){
...
});
```

Comment: Or just use a closure `(function($) { /* jqueryCode with $ here */ })(jQuery);`

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress already includes a copy of jquery just change the start of your code to:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

   function sumRows() {
    var sum = 0,
        total = $('#total');
    $('tr').each(function () {
        var amount = $(this).find('input[name="amount"]'),
            checkbox = $(this).find('input[name="include"]');
        if (checkbox.is(':checked') && amount.val().length > 0) {
            sum += parseInt(amount.val(), 10);
        }
    });
    total.text(sum);
}

   // calculate sum anytime checkbox is checked or amount is changed
   $('input[name="amount"], input[name="include"]').on('change keyup blur',   sumRows);

});
```

Now it should work ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
I have already did it before but thumps down :/ ..i have copy paste some simple click event codes from w3shools to my wp text editor  and its working fine..

Answer (score 0):

there are more ways to do this (its a summary of allready given answers):

as [theblackgigant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076876/jquery-not-working-in-my-wordpress-page#answer-33077485) answerd, you can:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  // you can code with "$" here: $('.someClass')
  ...
});
```

as [vard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076876/jquery-not-working-in-my-wordpress-page#comment-53973126) commented on Irvin Dominins answer, you can us a selfexecuting anonymous function:

```
(function($) { 
  // you can code with "$" here: $('.someClass')
  $(document).on('ready', function () {
    ...
  });
})(jQuery);
```

or you can do it with using "jQuery()" instead of "$()" or using .noConflict(), as [Irvin Dominin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076876/jquery-not-working-in-my-wordpress-page#answer-33077467) answered:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  // you can code with "jQuery" here: jQuery('.someClass')
  jQuery(document).on('ready', function () {
    ...
  });
});

$j=jQuery.noConflict();

// you can code with "$j" here: $j('.someClass')
$j(document).on('ready', function () {
  ...
});
```

i usually prefere the self executing function, because if code execution needs to be done before the document gets "ready" its easy to do here. And you can use $ which makes code easy to copy between projects or from other jquery related sources.

it is also possible to combine the .noConflict() (which is the preferred method of the jquery devs) method with the selfexecuting function, [source](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/):

```
jQuery_noConflict = jQuery.noConflict();

(function($){
  // you can code with "$" here: $('.someClass')
  $(document).on('ready', function () {
    ...
  });

})(jQuery_noConflict);
```